# Scrollbar duplicada com o jQuery Vegas

Tags: jquery, css

A Scrollbar aparece duas vezes ao clicar em alguma aba que seja maior que a dela:
[image: Scrollbar duplicada]

Estou usando o [Vegas](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) e o [jQuery Hashchange](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/).

Tavez seja este trecho de código do Vegas:

```
body .vegas-container {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  position: relative;
}
```

Mas eu não tenho idéia de como proceder neste caso.

Comment: Um link para o site seria interessante, porque pode ser alguma coisa no conteúdo que criaste.

Comment: Então, o link nem tem mais, alterei completamente o site, não uso mais o Vegas, infelizmente.